# Using pjax with page-specific javascript and css

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pjax

I want to use pjax in my application and basically have it working, but I can´t figure out how to use it with page-specific JS and CSS code.

I usually have one application-wide and one page-specific JS and CSS file per page.

The only solution I can think of in order to avoid collisions between several page-specific JS files is to manually unbind all page-specific event handlers when loading another page, but this would become super complex, because I would have to unbind *all* event handlers used in any page-specific code.

For CSS, the solution would be to increase the specificity e.g. by prefixing all selectors with a page-specific ID, which of course is possible, but not the most elegant solution in my opinion.

Has anybody found an elegant solution for using pjax with page-specific JS and CSS files?

Comment: Are the page-specific event handlers only for page-specific content?

Comment: Any luck figuring it out? I have the same issue..

Comment: Same issues here as well. I am getting a sense that pjax is more suited for static content websites. The moment you have interactivity in your pages, its hard to even get the event bindings and plugin inits right across the pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on the CSS and JS including.. I have posted the code to the github pjax page. Take a look [Including CSS and JS files via PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/pull/232)

Comment: That doesn't appear to unbind handlers on page change.